# How Can I Contact a Moderator?

Tags: support

I'm pretty sure I've stumbled on something heavily unethical going on on the site, and I'd like to present my evidence to a moderator.

How can I get in contact with a moderator?

Or can I get a moderator to contact me?

Comment: spill the beans?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can talk to us via chat, but that is visible to everybody. I think this is by design, so that everything is "in the open". So to your general point, I don't think there is a way to do that through the StackExchange system.

Moderators can contact **you**, but that's for violations. The main way for users to draw the moderators' attention to things is by flagging.